# JWT is being sent in cookies, but when I try for CSRF they are not sent

Tags: web-application, appsec, cookies, csrf, jwt

I am testing this application which sends JWT and CSRF token in cookies, I created a PoC file to test for CSRF, but only CSRF token is being sent in the PoC request and not JWT.

I was under the impression that cookies are always sent in all requests regardless of the domain sending those requests, this is the reason CSRF attacks are possible in the first place.

Why is JWT not being sent in CSRF PoC request?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the cookies are marked as [SameSite](https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/04/14/preventing-csrf-with-samesite-cookie-attribute/), or you are using a browser that has [SameSite as default behavior](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592).

Comment: Your answer could be more precise, though. `SameSite` is only the attribute name. It's the value used (if any) that will determine the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is the cookie and there is no difference what value is stored in it. It is only a string. You have to check all cookie attributes like: domain, path, flags.

From my experience first I would look for is *secure* flag. Often when developers are testing some feature on localhost they forget to use HTTPS with localhost (I do not recommend to set *secure=false*, as developers forgets sometimes about such things, and this can often be replicated to production environment).

Second flag is the *SameSite* which by default is set as "self" and if cookie used in cross-site request it disappears.